# esri JavaScript Spatial Analysis Services: Select appropriate helper services url from Portal for requested operation

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online, arcgis-platform

About 6 months ago I built a prototype JavaScript app which uses the spatial analysis service; FindNearest. [Find Nearest](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/analysis/api-reference/find-nearest.htm). I've posted this on GeoNet but haven't had much joy there.

The app ran fine for a few months, prompting users to log in to ArcGIS online, before submitting a task and returning results.

Now my geoprocessing job is failing with: Select appropriate helper services url from Portal for requested operation","params". See below for full JSON response. You can also debug yourself at [Rig Planner](http://www.deloitte-geospatial.com/rigplanner/) . Look at arcgis.js lines 215 to 255 to see me build my parameters object and submit the task. So what's changed? And what do I need to change to get my app returning results again?

```
{
jobId: "j1d25d7282f4b43fab8bd626a59908963",
jobStatus: "esriJobFailed",
results: { },
inputs: { },
messages:
[
]

{},
type: "esriJobMessageTypeError",
description: "{"error": {"code" : 0, "messageCode": "GPEXT_015","message": "Select appropriate helper services url from Portal for requested operation","params": {}}}"
{},
type: "esriJobMessageTypeError",
description: "{"messageCode": "AO_100030", "message": "FindNearest failed."}"
{},
type: "esriJobMessageTypeError",
description: "Failed to execute (FindNearest)."
{}
type: "esriJobMessageTypeError",
description: "Failed."
}
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to http://www.deloitte-geospatial.com/rigplanner/
2. Open your browser's developer tools (I'm using Chrome) and show the network
   tab
3. Search by Filter > Search. You do not need to change any of the
   default filter values
4. Enter a valid ArcGIS Online username and password and hit OK. I've setup a temp account for debugging
5. You should be able to see the
   api submit the gp task, then check it's status a few times before
   failing. When I examine the output of the final output I see
   jobStatus: esriJobFailed with an array of 4 messages. See the output
   from my original posting the JSON object.

As I say this app was working fine up until a couple of months ago, and should return 2 objects when successful. i) The nearestLayer containing the 10 nearest points to the little rig marker, and also ii) the connecting lines from the marker to each point. It's a fun little proof of concept that we'd love to get working again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to get esri support onto this one in the end. By changing the url of the analysis service to "http://analysis1.arcgis.com/rest/services/tasks/GPServer/FindNearest" the application now returns results for users in my ArcGIS Online Organization. Doesn't seem to work for trial accounts however.

Comment: Quick note - without knowing your original URL, I'm guessing its the "analysis1" (1) which solved it. Your account is probably tied to the set of servers on analysis1, not just analysis.

Comment: Ya, last note, the points you're using with it are on services1 (https://services1.arcgis.com/...), so you need analysis1 to match.